# Como posicionar uma imagem no reportlab usando pdfrw como flowable?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, reportlab

Estou usando o `reportlab` para gerar relatórios. Posso definir o processo de criação em quatro etapas: 1) pegar os dados via API, 2) filtrar os dados, 3) gerar os gráficos com o `matplotlib` e 4) inserir informações em PDF com o `reportlab`.

Eu encontrei [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712386/loading-matplotlib-object-into-reportlab/32021013#32021013) e [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690585/is-there-a-matplotlib-flowable-for-reportlab/50765404#50765404) resposta um `matplotlib` `flowable` para `ReportLab`. Fiz algumas alterações e copio abaixo a parte do código que interessa:

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Flowable
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfDict
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl


try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO
except ImportError:
    from io import BytesIO

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
style = styles['Normal']

#Informações caso queiram rodar o código
div = ['may/18', 'jun/18', 'jul/18', 'aug/18', 'sep/18', 'oct/18', 'nov/18', 'dec/18', 'jan/19', 'feb/19', 'mar/19', 'apr/19']
mes = [0, 15, 149, 0, 59, 0, 0, 101, 45, 25, 751.07, 5358.3]
acc = [0, 15, 164, 164, 223, 223, 223, 324, 369, 394, 1145.07, 6503.37]

class PdfImage(Flowable):
    """
    Generates a reportlab image flowable for matplotlib figures. It is initialized
    with either a matplotlib figure or a pointer to a list of pagexobj objects and
    an index for the pagexobj to be used.
    """
    def __init__(self, fig=None, width=200, height=200, cache=None, cacheindex=0):
        self.img_width = width
        self.img_height = height
        if fig is None and cache is None:
            raise ValueError("Either 'fig' or 'cache' must be provided")
        if fig is not None:
            imgdata = BytesIO()
            fig.savefig(imgdata, format='pdf')
            imgdata.seek(0)
            page, = PdfReader(imgdata).pages
            image = pagexobj(page)
            self.img_data = image
        else:
            self.img_data = None
        self.cache = cache
        self.cacheindex = cacheindex

    def wrap(self, width, height):
        return self.img_width, self.img_height

    def drawOn(self, canv, x, y, _sW=0):
        if _sW > 0 and hasattr(self, 'hAlign'):
            a = self.hAlign
            if a in ('CENTER', 'CENTRE', TA_CENTER):
                x += 0.5*_sW
            elif a in ('RIGHT', TA_RIGHT):
                x += _sW
            elif a not in ('LEFT', TA_LEFT):
                raise ValueError("Bad hAlign value " + str(a))
        canv.saveState()
        if self.img_data is not None:
            img = self.img_data
        else:
            img = self.cache[self.cacheindex]
        if isinstance(img, PdfDict):
            xscale = self.img_width / img.BBox[2]
            yscale = self.img_height / img.BBox[3]
            canv.translate(x, y)
            canv.scale(xscale, yscale)
            canv.doForm(makerl(canv, img))
        else:
            canv.drawImage(img, x, y, self.img_width, self.img_height)
        canv.restoreState()


class PdfImageCache(object):
    """
    Saves matplotlib figures to a temporary multi-page PDF file using the 'savefig'
    method. When closed the images are extracted and saved to the attribute 'cache'.
    The temporary PDF file is then deleted. The 'savefig' returns a PdfImage object
    with a pointer to the 'cache' list and an index for the figure. Use of this
    cache reduces duplicated resources in the reportlab generated PDF file.

    Use is similar to matplotlib's PdfPages object. When not used as a context
    manager, the 'close()' method must be explictly called before the reportlab
    document is built.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.pdftempfile = '_temporary_pdf_image_cache_.pdf'
        self.pdf = PdfPages(self.pdftempfile)
        self.cache = []
        self.count = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()

    def close(self, *args):
        self.pdf.close()
        pages = PdfReader(self.pdftempfile).pages
        pages = [pagexobj(x) for x in pages]
        self.cache.extend(pages)
        os.remove(self.pdftempfile)

    def savefig(self, fig, width=200, height=200):
        self.pdf.savefig(fig)
        index = self.count
        self.count += 1
        return PdfImage(width=width, height=height, cache=self.cache, cacheindex=index)



def make_report_cached_figs(outfn):
    """
    Makes a dummy report with nfig matplotlib plots using PdfImageCache
    to reduce PDF file size.
    """

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(outfn)
    style = styles["Normal"]
    story = []

    with PdfImageCache() as pdfcache:

            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
            plt.bar(div, acc, width = 0.8, color = 'silver', label = 'Year')
            plt.bar(div, mes, width = 0.4, color = 'k', label = 'Month', alpha = 0.5)
            plt.legend()
            plt.xticks(rotation=60)
            plt.close()
            img0 = pdfcache.savefig(fig, width=185, height=135)
            img0.drawOn(doc, 0, 100)

            story.append(img0)

    doc.build(story)

make_report_cached_figs("Test.pdf")
```

Meu problema está no método `drawOn`, mais especificamente no primeiro argumento. No código acima eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError: 'SimpleDocTemplate' object has no attribute 'saveState'
```

Se eu substituir `doc = SimpleDocTemplate(outfn)` por `doc = canvas.Canvas(outfn)` eu recebo outro erro:

```
img = self.cache[self.cacheindex]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Tenho procurado informações na documentação oficial e no código fonte mas não obtive sucesso. Então, **como consigo posicionar a imagem?** (usando o método drawOn ou não)